# NoReverseMatch at / having difficulties passing datasource to form action method

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

> NoReverseMatch at /providers/121/update/
>   Reverse for 'provider_update' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['providers/(?P\d+)/update/']

I know why the NoReverseMatch error is thrown, because the url cannot find parameters being identified. However, I don't understand why my parameters are not being passed to the right view. When I pass a var holding the parameters ID or PK it recognizes it as None, for some reason. I have looked at similiar questions, but they aren't having issues passing the data to the form action. Any help is appreciated!! Thanks

partial_provider_update.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'provider_update' form.instance.id %}" class="js-provider-update-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Update Provider</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% include 'providers/includes/partial_provider_form.html' %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update provider</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

partial_provider_list.html

```
      {% for provider in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ provider.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ provider.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ provider.organization }}</td>
            <td>{{ provider.emr }}</td>
            <td>{{ provider.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}</td>
            <td style="width: 100px; vertical-align: center; padding-top: 9px">
                <button type="button"
                    style="height: 25px; font-size: 16px;width: 50px; padding: 0px"
                    class="btn btn-warning btn-sm js-update-provider"
                    data-url="{% url 'provider_update' provider.id %}">
                        Edit
                </button>
            </td>
         {% empty %}
            <tr>
              <td colspan="5" class="text-center bg-warning">No Providers</td>
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, TemplateView
from providers.models import Provider
from providers import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Provider.objects.all().order_by("id"), template_name='providers/home.html')),
    url(r'^create/', views.provider_create, name='provider_create'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/update/', views.provider_update, name='provider_update'),
]
```

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import JsonResponse
from providers.models import Provider
from .forms import ProviderForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'providers/home.html')

def save_provider_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            object_list = Provider.objects.all()
            data['html_provider_list'] = render_to_string('providers/includes/partial_provider_list.html', { 'object_list' : object_list })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = ProviderForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)

def provider_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProviderForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = ProviderForm()
    return save_provider_form(request, form, 'providers/includes/partial_provider_create.html')

def provider_update(request, pk):
    provider = get_object_or_404(Provider, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProviderForm(request.POST, instance=provider)
    else:
        form = ProviderForm(instance=provider)
    return save_provider_form(request, form, 'providers/includes/partial_provider_update.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `save_provider_form()` function.

See my comments in this code below:

```
def save_provider_form(...):

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        ...
        else:
            ...
    else:
        # ################### #
        # HERE IS THE PROBLEM #
        # ################### #
        form = ProviderForm() # form is re-initialized with no instance
```

In `provider_update()` function if `request.method` is `GET`, you are initializing the form with an `instance`, but in `save_provider_form()` if `request.method` is `GET`, you are re-initializing the form with no instance. So the `id` is `None`, because the instance is `None`.

Comment: oh wow. that so sloppy of me. I spent over 3 hours trying to figure this out. thanks so much